# Change Plone default URL for authenticated users

Tags: plone

I need to change the default URL for authenticated users. For example, a request for root site will response:

1. [site-root]/wellcome01 (default url, set by plone configuration interface), for an anonymous user
2. [site-root]/wellcome02 (set by some **resource**) for an authenticated user

So what's the best solution to implement this **resource**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got several options

1.

You can add a `index_html` Python Script in your plone root, with the following code.

```
if context.portal_membership.isAnonymousUser():
    return context.REQUEST.RESPONSE.redirect('welcome01')
else:
    return context.REQUEST.RESPONSE.redirect('welcome02')
```

2.

I personally don't like not versioned code on my site, so I advice you to write a BrowserView, which handles de redirect

```
from Products.Five.browser import BrowserView
from plone import api


class RootRedirector(BrowserView):

    def __call__(self):

        if api.user.is_anonymous()
            return self.request.RESPONSE.redirect('welcome01')
        else:
            return self.request.RESPONSE.redirect('welcome02')
```

You may regsiter this view only for the SiteRoot (Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.siteroot.IPloneSiteRoot)

Comment: due to lack of time, we'd followed the solution 1, by the way, already implemented. Thanks for the examples.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to just react to login events, you can adapt the following, which will redirect on the first-ever login only (and you probably want `IUserLoggedInEvent` instead):

configure.zcml:

```
<subscriber for="Products.PlonePAS.events.IUserInitialLoginInEvent"
            handler=".hellonewbie.showIntroPage" />
```

hellonewbie.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from zope.app.component.hooks import getSite

USER_ROLE     = 'Member'
INTRO_PAGE_ID = 'new-user-info'

def showIntroPage(event):
    """Login event handler: first login.

    For proper users (i.e. Member role) that have
    never logged in before, redirect them to a page
    that tells them about the system.
    """

    user = event.object

    if user.has_role(USER_ROLE):
        # yup, redirect the guy, he/she's new.

        portal = getSite()
        request = getattr(portal, "REQUEST", None)
        if request:
            infopage = portal.restrictedTraverse(INTRO_PAGE_ID, None)
            if infopage:
                request.response.redirect(infopage.absolute_url())
```

Comment: We don't choose this solution but its helps on other code case. Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 3):

Or, just use one view with two elements, one only visible if not logged-in, the other only, if logged-in, via TAL-conditions.